# Quickest way to replace series of characters from start and end in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a requirement to replace the first and last 2 characters of a string with asterisks(*) in SQL, example:

**Input** : 123456

**Output** : `**34**`

This is how I've done it, is there anyway I can improve the script below?(make it shorter, call less built in functions to get the required output etc)

```
 DECLARE @Number VARCHAR(64)
SET @Number = '123456789'

IF(LEN(@Number) >= 5)
BEGIN

--Remove the first two characters
SET @Number = SUBSTRING(@Number,3,LEN(@Number))

--Remove the last two characters
SET @Number = SUBSTRING(@Number,0,LEN(@Number)- 1)

--Add two asterisks at front and end
SEt @Number = '**' + @Number + '**'

SELECT @Number
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
DECLARE @Number VARCHAR(64)
SET @Number = '123456789'

select '**'+substring(@Number,3,len(@Number)-4)+'**'
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17701/0)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`STUFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function

```
SET @Number = STUFF(STUFF(@Number,1,2,'**'),LEN(@Number)-1,2,'**')
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17702)**